# Mussels taking more than 20 minutes to open and curl

Tags: mussels

I just got a mussel pot and have used it twice to make mussels. From all the recipes it’s supposed to take 5-6 minutes of steaming until the mussels open completely. I used about 125 ml of white wine for 1 kg of blue mussels. I brought the wine to a boil, then put the mussels in. Then I kept it on high heat for a while because the cold mussels would cool down everything, and when I heard it started boiling again I did what I usually do when steaming things: I set it to a low heat, just enough to keep the liquid boiling.

I didn’t time it exactly but it took well over 20 minutes until most of the mussels had opened up and curled into a ball-like shape (rather than having the flesh stretched along the shells). After 10 minutes none of them had opened.

The next time I figured the problem was that I had kept a low heat after it started boiling, so this time I kept a medium-high heat throughout the process. This time I went on for 22 minutes, with heat high enough to keep 1 litre of water boiling hard, even though it was only 125 ml of white wine. After steaming with the wine at that heat for 22 minutes my kitchen smelt like a destillery with the sharp alcohol smell, most of the mussels had opened, but only about half of them had curled. As before, after 10 minutes none of them had opened.

I believe the mussels are supposed to both open and curl when they are done. I thought perhaps they were bad mussels, but they were harvested 6 days before cooking, and were supposed to be good for 6 more days. They had only spent a few hours in my fridge, they smelled fine and almost all were either closed, or closed themselves after being tapped. If mussels are overcooked they are supposed to go rubbery, but I would rather say the flesh was soggy and lacked firmness/consistency. From what I read, that’s a sign of being undercooked rather than overcooked.

So what am I doing wrong if it takes over 20 minutes rather than 5-6 minutes before they open and curl? Should I use more liquid, less liquid, high or low heat? Fewer mussels? I might add one more thing: The mussel pot I got has a base, the part that gets heated by my induction hob, that is only about 10 cm diameter, while the pot itself is about 18 cm diameter. I wonder if perhaps this very small base is part of the problem, if I should instead use a regular pot where the base is the same diameter as the pot itself. I have no idea whether it makes a difference. Also perhaps I should use a pot with a clear lid, so I don’t have to open it to check if they are open. I try to do that rarely anyway.

[Picture of the mussel pot](https://traktoren.no/media/catalog/product/cache/c4a11e66ee9433953f551e1adfcb16b9/k/i/kitchencraftblaskjellgryte24cm_1.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by mussels curling? I've never heard that term.

Comment: First, I've never heard of "curling" as a criterion for mussel edibility before.  Second, how big were these mussels?  The larger the mussel, the longer it will take to overheat.  Third, 6 minutes would be on the low end of the time it can take mussels to open; taking 12 minutes certainly isn't unusual, but 22 minutes is pretty high. The induction burner seems unlikely to be part of the problem if the pot was filled with steam.

Comment: OK, it seems that term wasn’t clear. When mussels are not cooked, the flesh is stretched out alongside the shells. When they are served in a restaurant, they are shaped more like an oval “ball”, for a lack of a better term. Certainly not stretched out alongside the shells anyway. I know from experience that when the mussels first open, they arent always shaped like this immediately, it may take a little more steaming before they form this shape. This is what I mean by “curling”.

Comment: According to the website of the supermarket where I bought the mussels, when this doesn’t happen it’s a sign of mussels being dead before cooking. They say it’s a better sign than mussels not closing when you tap them, because this can also happen due to being stored in the fridge which makes them slow to respond. According to the store’s website, anyway. This source is in my native language (Norwegian) so I can’t link to it.

Comment: @FuzzyChef, I didn't know how to respond with notification, but my responses are above.

Comment: My first thought would be to try adding more liquid.  It's possible that 125ml of wine isn't creating enough steam to carry the heat to all the mussels.